# checkboxes that append to a model in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model, which will be related to a number of other models. Think of a stack overflow question, for example, where it is a question related to tags. The final Object might look as follows before a `POST` or a `PUT`:

```
{
  id: 28329332,
  title: "checkboxes that append to a model in Angular.js",
  tags: [{
    id: 5678,
    name: "angularjs"
  }, {
    id: 890,
    name: "JavaScript"
  }]
}
```

So far, I have the following controller:

```
.controller('CreateQuestionCtrl',
    function($scope, $location, Question, Tag) {
      $scope.question = new Question();
      $scope.page = 1;
      $scope.getTags = function() {
        Tag.query({ page: $scope.page }, function(data) {
          $scope.tags = data;
        }, function(err) {
          // to do, error when they try to use a page that doesn't exist
        })
      };
      $scope.create = function() {
        $scope.question.$save(function(data) {
          $location.path("/question/" + data.id);
        });
      };
      $scope.$watch($scope.page, $scope.getTags);
    }
  )
```

So I display all of the tags, paginated, on the page. I want them to be able to select the given tags and append it to my model so that it can be saved.

How can I create a checkbox interface where it updates the `$scope.question` with the selected other models?

---

EDIT: think I might be part of the way there

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="tag in tags.objects">
  <label><input
    type="checkbox"
    ng-change="setTag(tag.id)"
    ng-model="tag"
  >&nbsp;{{ tag.name }}
</div>
```

Then on the controller

```
$scope.setTag = function(id) {
  Tag.get({id: id}, function(data) {
    // don't know what now
  })
}
```

Comment: So you want a check-box created and bind to each of the tags?

Comment: yes, I want some sort of `ng-checked` event which will take the entire model and append it to my `Question.tags`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it takes a directive to approach your goal [Take a look at the plunker I wrote for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/418uD49L8C946g500Y7Q?p=preview). As you can see, in the list of selected tags the `text` property of each tag is displayed, it means that the object structure is kept. In your case, you would bind the `$scope.question.tags` array as the `collection` attribute and each tag from the `$scope.tags` as the  `element` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Kalesh/pen/MYEREL) for multiple check-boxes bound to the same model.

HTML

```
<html ng-app="codePen" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Multiple Checkboxes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng:controller="MainCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="tag in model.tags">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tag.enabled" ng-change="onChecked()"> {{tag.name}} 
    </label>
    <p>tags: {{model.tags}}</p>
    <p> checkCount: {{counter}}  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('codePen', []);    
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.model = { id: 28329332,
        title: "checkboxes that append to a model in Angular.js",
        tags: [{
          id: 5678,
          name: "angularjs",
          enabled: false
        }, {
          id: 890,
          name: "JavaScript",
          enabled: true
        }]
        };
      $scope.counter = 0;
      $scope.onChecked = function (){
        $scope.counter++;
      };
 });
```

Comment: not sure if that answer will necessarily be extensible, as I could have hundreds of tags. I'd like to mostly append to my existing model

Comment: I have updated answer with ng-change which can track checkbox change. Ideally you should convert the above into a directive which could be bound to some model.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [great library called checklist-model](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) worth mentioning if anyone is looking up this question. All I had to do was this, more or less:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="tag in tags">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="question.tags" checklist-value="tags"> {{ tag.name }}
  </label>
</div>
```

Found this on googling "directives for angular checkbox".